# Not able to click nb-checkbox of Nebular theme angular

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular7, nebular

I am new to Nebular theme. I have a checkbox but it's not working.

HTML

```
<nb-checkbox [value]="checked" (change)="toggle($event)"></nb-checkbox>
```

TypeScript

```
  toggle(checked: any) {    
    this.checked = checked.target.checked;
  }
```

Module.ts

```
//import
import { NbCheckboxModule } from '@nebular/theme';

imports: [NbCheckboxModule]
```

toggle function is being called fine but checkbox is not being checked.

I have been debugging since a long time but couldn't identify the issue. Any suggestions about what could be wrong? Thank you.

Angular Version: 7.1

Nebular version: ^3.5.0

Comment: Did you test by setting this.checked =  true just for debugging proposal?

Comment: @AbelValdez yes I did. I even set true directly to [value] attribute but still it does not show it checked.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use it like in [these](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/checkbox/examples#nbcheckboxcomponent) examples
it works with `value` and `checked` inputs

```
<nb-checkbox [checked]="checked" (checkedChange)="toggle($event)">Toggle me</nb-checkbox>
```

i created stackblitz for you with working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nb-checkbox?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually I am using an old version of nebular(I should mention in the question). checkedChange cannot be used with old version.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your HTML:

```
<nb-checkbox status="primary" [value]="checked" (change)="setCheckedStatus($event)">Primary</nb-checkbox>
```

Add the following in your component.ts file:

```
checked: true; // declare this variable in your component
setCheckedStatus(checked) {
    console.log('checked', checked.target.checked);
    this.checked = checked.target.checked; // your variable
}
```